# AngularJs How to use Directive Specific Fields alone but not all fields available inside Directive

Tags: angularjs

EX:testDirective
    I have one directive(testDirective) have some of the fields implemented like 
    Text,Textarea,select,checkbox,radio buttons.Here I want to use this implemented directive  in some other view page like html page by placing inside div tags

```
                    ex:<div test-directive></div>
```

what I have doubt is I dont want to use all fields which is available inside directive.I need only Textarea alone so how can i use please give me example for this.

Comment: code please, create a fiddle